# Database Structure Differences between Web & Mobile Development

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I would like to know the difference between the structure of database on mobile (Eg; SQLite) and the structure of database on web.

> For example, on mobile app development, the database table related to
>   user will only have one row. But, in web (back-end), there would be
>   many row for user table. So, even though we only have one row, we
>   still keep creating the user table in SQLite ?

In my App, all the data are coming from Web Services. And I would like to support full offline support. So, it is like i need to create SQLite structure and tables for everything I received from web services.

> The other data are making sense. But, for user, there gotta be some
>   logic in here to for that specifically. I need to store every data I
>   am storing in my web-services. **But, still, it feels wrong to create a
>   user table which will only have one row in any given situation**.

Let's say in Facebook App. News Feeds are storing in database table. But, how they store the logged in user info for offline ? By creating a user table with only one row ?

Answer (score 0):

NO, If I was to do something like that, then the db on the app would be quite different from what is on the server.Things to consider:
On server your user db stores many different users details like name, age, location, phone number etc. While on app you really don't need all the users, but just the current user's details.

If it was something like facebook then  On server I would have users tables, photos, friends, posts, etc. On server all the users posts, comments, photos  would be saved BUT on the apps end I would only have the currently logged in user details. The tables doesn't need to be the same, you could have less tables on the app.

Comment: Exactly my point. So, how would you store user information along with other information ?

Comment: give me your scenario and I will help you design the sqlite database

Comment: Hay Kevin, the scenario is very common. At any given time, the user table will only have one row and other tables will have more than one row acd:to Business Logic.